# OSError: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, 64-bit, torch, oserror

I got this error in raspberry pi 64 bit OS when im importing torch
"from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence"

So far I have used the following  solution:

export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1:/$LD_PRELOAD
and
source ~/.bashrc

But still getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Okay , I got it solved by putting this line at the beginning of the code:

```
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pad_sequence
```

I don't know how it worked and solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the pre-built aarch64 wheel from PyTorch seems to encounter this error on 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS.

However, a wheel built on-device seems to work fine. If you don't want to build it yourself, the wheel built by Q-engineering on an RPi seems to work without issues. Check it out [here](https://qengineering.eu/install-pytorch-on-raspberry-pi-4.html) (RPi 3B & 4, 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS).